# Benchmark for closure, anonymous function and ordinary function

Tags: go

I test some function and I don't understand why time execution different for closure and anonymous function:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func X(p *int) {
    *p += 1
}

func main() {
    n := 1000000000
    t0 := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        p := 0
        x := func() {
            p += 1
        }
        x()
    }
    fmt.Printf("Closure: %v\n", time.Since(t0))

    t0 = time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        p := 0
        func() {
            p += 1
        }()
    }
    fmt.Printf("Anonymous function: %v\n", time.Since(t0))

    t0 = time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        p := 0
        X(&p)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Function: %v\n", time.Since(t0))
    return
}
```

Results:

> 558.84667ms
>
> 267.847834ms
>
> 271.102576ms

If I move define of variable out of cyclic, time is equal.

Comment: The first and second examples are both closures (they close over variables from the outer scope) and are both anonymous functions (the functions are unnamed). Also try benchmarking with Go's included benchmarking tools rather than rolling your own, the included tools are very well made. Lastly. this kind of micro-benchmark is very likely to yield inaccurate performance data.

Comment: If you divide your times by 1000000000, you get .27-.56 nanoseconds per call -- your benchmarks do basically nothing and you're measuring a few meaningless overhead instructions. (you should also use the builtin benchmarking facility, rather than trying to time it manually)

Comment: It doesn't surprise me that a billion variable assignments take some time.  This is also in the class of "optimization" where, unless you're seriously considering assembly as an implementation path, the clock cycle or two you save isn't going to matter at all, and you're better off focusing your performance measurement and tuning efforts elsewhere.

Comment: @Adrian bench to yield the same results

Comment: @JimB I did the same test for more large n. The same result. The bench gives is the same.

Comment: @DavidMaze As you can see the first and the second examples create local variable. But the first example works longer than second.

Comment: @hedgehogues: yes, the benchmark gives the same results, but again the results don't mean anything. The difference is **.3ns**! If a single clock cycle makes any difference in your code, you need to be writing assembly because the compiler isn't going to guarantee these differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amongst other things, some code generation and some optimizations are easier to do than others. See the Go gc compiler source code for details.

```
$ go version
go version devel +e68ac45172 Fri Jul 20 16:04:01 2018 +0000 linux/amd64
```

Unoptimized:

```
$ go test bench_test.go -bench=. -benchmem -gcflags='-N'
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkClosure-4         1    2621664326 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkAnonymous-4       1    1995507678 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkFunction-4        1    2297303813 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
```

Optimized:

```
$ go test bench_test.go -bench=. -benchmem
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkClosure-4         2     585091582 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkAnonymous-4       5     287299925 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkFunction-4        5     287710165 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
```

`bench_test.go`:

```
package main

import "testing"

func X(p *int) {
    *p += 1
}

var N = 1000000000

func BenchmarkClosure(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
            p := 0
            x := func() {
                p += 1
            }
            x()
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkAnonymous(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
            p := 0
            func() {
                p += 1
            }()
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkFunction(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
            p := 0
            X(&p)
        }
    }
}
```